# Jasper Reports - How to sort crosstab when using multiple measures

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a crosstab in Jasper Studio which shows Sales, Quantity, and Percentage Margin totals for a client. The major complexity of this crosstab is the Percentage Margin, as this cannot use a simple sum, count, or average in the total to report the correct figure, it needs to be calculated separately. To combat this I have created 4 measures:

1. for the main data (a combination of sales, quantity, and margin in 1 field)
2. for the right-hand total
3. for the bottom-line summary, and
4. for the Overall totals field where total and summary meet.

[image]

The client requires the crosstab to be sorted at runtime using the interactive sorting feature of Jasper Server. This is working, but only as long as the crosstab uses one measure. As soon as I add the other 3 measures, the sorting option for all columns greys-out, and the sort no longer works for the client.

Is there any way I can make this sorting work, even when I use multiple Measures? Or is there another way I can display the information I require using a single measure instead?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to set the [net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.column.header.sort.measure.index](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.column.header.sort.measure.index) property on an element in the column header cell to the 0-based index of the measure that you want the column sorted by.

As in

```
<columnGroup ...>
    ...
    <crosstabColumnHeader>
        <cellContents>
            <textField>
                <reportElement ...>
                    <!-- sort by the second measure -->
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.column.header.sort.measure.index" value="1"/>
                </reportElement>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, dada. This unfortunately doesn't resolve the problem, I'm not trying to sort by a different measure, I'm unable to sort by _any_ measure as soon as I include more than one in the crosstab.

If there are other "hidden" properties like this available to set one of them may be the solution to this

Comment: When you have more than one measure you need to explicitly say (by setting the property) which one to use for sorting.  If the property is not set, sorting will be disabled because the engine doesn't want to pick an arbitrary measure to sort by.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I did try it several ways, so maybe I'm not understanding it fully. Please allow me to elaborate so I can try again. For the `index value="1" ` is there any way I can determine which number I need to enter here? Is it as simple as 1,2,3,4 corresponds to my 4 measures?

The other strange thing is the sorting does appear to still work on the name on the left-hand side, but no other column, so if it can sort correctly on that column at runtime, why not any of the others also?

Comment: The value of the property is the 0-based index of the column.  So value="0" corresponds to the first measure, value="1" to the second measure, and so on.